# How can I check with powershell if an account is allowed to RPD to a server

Tags: powershell, rdp

I want to write a script to check that an account can access a server via RDP.
I just want to check if the connection will be possible, I don't want to imput the credentials.
So I am searching for a way to see if the RDP responds with the credential prompt to close the session.

Any help will be great.
Thank you!

Comment: well checking if port 3389 is open for RDP isn't too out of the question. `Test-NetConnection` can do just that but, something even better, is that it can check for common TCP ports such as RDP: `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "computer1" -CommonTCPPort "RDP"`. You can script it out as well passing that same computername to `mstsc /v:"computer1"` for the connection to it. Unless I misunderstood you correctly and you want to check to see if the actual account is allowed to remote in using RDP?